# insert multipla values in a single column

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I created following table in SQL Server 2000

```
create table book(id integer, author varchar(20))
```

In this, each book may have 1 or more authors.

My question is that, how can insert more value to author column like as follows.

```
id   author
1    pooja merry james
2    robert stephen
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a many-to-many relationship between books and authors, so you need to create an independent table of authors and then introduce a junction table to map books to authors.

[image]

Comment: @Pooja: I've added a diagram to my answer.